# spawn ffmpeg process fails with permission denied

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, spawn

I'm trying to spawn a ffmpeg process to encode some audio files to hls compatible mpegts files. I need to feed the data via pipe in order to handle the live stream part. I'm using the code below to spawn my process:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream('./audio.mp3');
var child = spawn('ffmpeg',
  ['-y', '-i', 'pipe:', '-c', 'aac', '-b:a', '32k', '-hls_segment_type', 'mpegts', '-hls_time', 1, '-hls_list_size', 0, './' + req.body.uri + '_32k.m3u8'], {
    env: process.env,
    stdio: ['pipe', 1, 2]
  }
);
file.pipe(child.stdin);
```

strangely I get `pipe:: Permission denied` from stderr of ffmpeg.

Comment: I found a workaround, but I'm not satisfied with the result. Right now I'm using `cat` executable to echo the file to the ffmpeg process. I guess ffmpeg pipe and nodejs pipe is not compatible.

`var child = spawn(['cat', '|' ,'ffmpeg', '-i', 'pipe:', ...]); fs.pipe(child.stdin);`

Comment: or just try to run as sudo ...?

Comment: @BookOfZeus sudo would prompt the password screen, this process will be in a headless environment.

Comment: ```username ALL = NOPASSWD : ALL``` - https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-being-prompted-for-a-password-by-sudo

Comment: @BookOfZeus I'm not sure if enabling such security issue is the way to go.

Comment: Agreed, all depends on the usage